# Handle CustomOverlayViewController from AVPlayerViewController

Tags: tvos, apple-tv

I am looking for customOverlayViewController, which is from tvOS 13.0 onwards. The flow is
`customOverlayViewController←UITransitionView←AVHostView←UIVisualEffectView←UIVisualEffectSubview.`
This UIVisualEffectSubview contains background colour, so I want to change this to clear colour. May I know how can I do this.

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score -2):

I tried followed way, it is working please check

```
if #available(tvOS 13.0, *) {
    if let customVC = self.playerVC?.customOverlayViewController {
        let view = customVC.view?.superview
        if let view1 = view?.superview {
            for view in view1.subviews {
                for view2 in view.subviews {
                    if view2 is UIVisualEffectView {
                        view2.alpha = 0.0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please elaborate the question